# QWebEngine doesn't handle correctly relative url link

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on an offline web browser that open content from archive files.
I use the QWebEngineView class to display the content and it works for most of the files I use.
But I have the case where there are links whose relative url contains "../" at the beginning and Qt doesn't seem to correctly interpret this type of path. 
For example on the page which url is "question/8/turing-completeness-in-conlangs.html", there is a link like this  and it redirects to "question/tag/grammar/1.html".

Is this behaviour normal ? Is there anywhere I can modify it ?

I already tried to fix this problem in the QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler::requestStarted method but the url of QWebEngineUrlRequestJob *request is already wrong

Comment: Are you opening the initial URL using `QUrl::fromLocalFile`?

Comment: No, I manually set up the url like this QUrl url("zim://"+id+".zim/");